# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Fortnite bot with discord.py for discord, I'm trying to add store functionality right now but when I try to add another command recognizer I get the error `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method` in the console.

the code causing it is

```
  if message.content.startswith(COMMAND_PREFIX + 'stats', COMMAND_PREFIX + 'fnstore'):
words = message.content.split(' ', 2)
word = message.content.split(' ', 1)
```

If I remove `, COMMAND_PREFIX + 'fnstore'` It starts working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`
>   Return `True` if string starts
>   with the `prefix`, otherwise return `False`. **`prefix` can also be a tuple of
>   prefixes to look for.** [..]

You're trying to pass two string arguments here, which is the wrong way to use `startswith`. I presume you want to use the highlighted way above and *pass a tuple*:

```
message.content.startswith( (COMMAND_PREFIX + 'stats', COMMAND_PREFIX + 'fnstore') )
```